# Get the emails from formula field from records and send mails to them

Tags: apex, trigger

Can Someone guide me on how I use the formula field value which I want to use for sending Emails?
Here is the code I've written but that field is returning a null value.

> Here, Client_Manager_Email_ID__c and Project_Manager_Email__c is
> formula field.

**TriggerHandler:**

```
public class ReleaseHandler {
    public static void SendMails(List<Release__c>newReleaseList){
        try{
            if(newreleaseList!=null){
                List<String> ManagersEmail=new List<String>();
                List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> Allmails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
                for(Release__c r:newReleaseList){
                    ManagersEmail.add(r.Client_Manager_Email_ID__c);
                    ManagersEmail.add(r.Project_Manager_Email__c);
                }
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setToAddresses(ManagersEmail);
                mail.setSubject('New Release');
                mail.setHtmlBody('Dear Manager, New Release is available on your Project.');
                Allmails.add(mail);
                Messaging.sendEmail(Allmails);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('Exception : '+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Trigger:**

```
trigger ReleaseTrigger on Release__c (after insert) {
    if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isinsert){
        ReleaseHandler.SendMails(trigger.new);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the definitions of those formula fields?

Comment: @sander-de-jong It's coming from two different parent objects (Project and Client)